# Apache Beam Resampling of columns based on date

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am using ApacheBeam to process data and trying to achieve the following.

1. read the data from CSV file. (Completed )
2. Group the records based on Customer ID  (Completed)
3. Resample the data based on month and calculate the sum for that particular month.

Detailed Explanation:

I have a CSV file as shown below.

| customerId | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:89481 | 11/14/2012 | 124 |
| BS:89480 | 11/14/2012 | 234 |
| BS:89481 | 11/10/2012 | 189 |
| BS:89480 | 11/02/2012 | 987 |
| BS:89481 | 09/14/2012 | 784 |
| BS:89480 | 11/14/2012 | 056 |

Intermediate stage:
Grouping it by customerId and sorting it by date

| customerId | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:89481 | 09/14/2012 | 784 |
| BS:89481 | 11/10/2012 | 189 |
| BS:89481 | 11/14/2012 | 124 |
| BS:89480 | 11/02/2012 | 987 |
| BS:89480 | 11/14/2012 | 234 |
| BS:89480 | 11/14/2012 | 056 |

**Expected output on( resampling)**
Here, we calculate the sum of all the amounts for that particular month for the individual customers.  Eg: the customer BS:89481 has two spends for the month of November, so we have calculated the sum for that month (124 + 189).

| customerId | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:89481 | 09/30/2012 | 784 |
| BS:89481 | 11/30/2012 | 313 |
| BS:89480 | 11/02/2012 | 1277 |

I was able to complete step1 and step2, not sure how to implement step3.

Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaFile);

```
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

    // Reading schema
    org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema beamSchema = AvroUtils.toBeamSchema(schema);

    final PCollectionTuple tuples = pipeline

            // Reading csv input
            .apply("1", FileIO.match().filepattern(csvFile.getAbsolutePath()))

            // Reading files that matches conditions //PRashanth needs to be looked at
            .apply("2", FileIO.readMatches())

            // Reading schema and validating with schema and converts to row and returns
            // valid and invalid list
            .apply("3", ParDo.of(new FileReader(beamSchema)).withOutputTags(FileReader.validTag(),
                    TupleTagList.of(invalidTag())));

    // Fetching only valid rows

    final PCollection<Row> rows = tuples.get(FileReader.validTag()).setCoder(RowCoder.of(beamSchema));

    // Step2
    //Convert row to KV for grouping
    StringToKV stringtoKV = new StringToKV();
    stringtoKV.setColumnName("customerId");
    PCollection<KV<String, Row>> kvOrderRows = rows.apply(ParDo.of(stringtoKV)).setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), rows.getCoder()));
            //setCoder(KvCoder.of(VoidCoder.of()), rows.getCoder()));

    
    // Obtain a PCollection of KeyValue class of 
    PCollection<KV<String,Iterable<Row>>> kvIterableForm = kvOrderRows.apply(GroupByKey.<String,Row>create());
```

**Update**:

Schema Transform:

```
    {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "Entry",
      "namespace" : "transform",
      "fields" : [  {
        "name" : "customerId",
        "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
      }, {
        "name" : "date",
        "type" : [ "long", "null" ]
      }, {
        "name" : "amount",
        "type" : [ "double", "null" ]
      }]
    }
```

CSV File

| customerId | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:89481 | 11/14/2012 | 124 |
| BS:89480 | 11/14/2012 | 234 |
| BS:89481 | 11/10/2012 | 189 |
| BS:89480 | 11/02/2012 | 987 |
| BS:89481 | 09/14/2012 | 784 |
| BS:89480 | 11/14/2012 | 056 |

```
class StringToKV1 extends DoFn<Row, KV<String, Row>> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8093837716944809689L;
        String columnName=null;

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
            Row row = context.element();
            context.output(KV.of(row.getValue(columnName), row));
        }
        
        public void setColumnName(String columnName) {
            this.columnName = columnName;
        }
    }
```

Code:

```
        public class GroupByTest {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("We are about to start!!");

                final File schemaFile = new File(
                        "C:\\AI\\Workspace\\office\\lombok\\artifact\\src\\main\\resources\\schema_transform2.avsc");

                File csvFile = new File(
                        "C:\\AI\\Workspace\\office\\lombok\\artifact\\src\\main\\resources\\CustomerRequest-case2.csv");
                Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaFile);

                Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

                // Reading schema
                org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema beamSchema = AvroUtils.toBeamSchema(schema);

                final PCollectionTuple tuples = pipeline

                        // Reading csv input
                        .apply("1", FileIO.match().filepattern(csvFile.getAbsolutePath()))

                        // Reading files that matches conditions //PRashanth needs to be looked at
                        .apply("2", FileIO.readMatches())

                        // Reading schema and validating with schema and converts to row and returns
                        // valid and invalid list
                        .apply("3", ParDo.of(new FileReader(beamSchema)).withOutputTags(FileReader.validTag(),
                                TupleTagList.of(invalidTag())));

                // Fetching only valid rows
                final PCollection<Row> rows = tuples.get(FileReader.validTag()).setCoder(RowCoder.of(beamSchema));

                // Transformation
                //Convert row to KV
                StringToKV1 stringtoKV1 = new StringToKV1();
                stringtoKV1.setColumnName("customerId");
                PCollection<KV<String, Row>> kvOrderRows = rows.apply(ParDo.of(stringtoKV1)).setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), rows.getCoder()));

                
                // Will throw error
                // rows.apply(Group.byFieldNames("customerId", "date").aggregateField("amount", Sum.ofIntegers(), //"totalAmount"));
                System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  "+Group.byFieldNames("customerId", "date")
                 .aggregateField("amount", Sum.ofIntegers(), "totalAmount").getName());                 
                
                pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
                System.out.println("The end");

            }

            private static String getColumnValue(String columnName, Row row, Schema sourceSchema) {
                String type = sourceSchema.getField(columnName).schema().getType().toString().toLowerCase();
                LogicalType logicalType = sourceSchema.getField(columnName).schema().getLogicalType();
                if (logicalType != null) {
                    type = logicalType.getName();
                }

                switch (type) {
                case "string":
                    return row.getString(columnName);
                case "int":
                    return Objects.requireNonNull(row.getInt32(columnName)).toString();
                case "bigint":
                    return Objects.requireNonNull(row.getInt64(columnName)).toString();
                case "double":
                    return Objects.requireNonNull(row.getDouble(columnName)).toString();
                case "timestamp-millis":
                    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(Objects.requireNonNull(row.getDateTime("eventTime")).getMillis()).toString();

                default:
                    return row.getString(columnName);

                }
            }



        }
```

**Corrected Code:**

```
        final Group.CombineFieldsByFields<Row> combine = Group.<Row>byFieldNames("customerId", "date")
                .aggregateField("amount", Sum.ofDoubles(), "sumAmount");

        final PCollection<Row> aggregagte = rows.apply(combine);

        PCollection<String> pOutput = aggregagte.apply(ParDo.of(new RowToString()));
```

The output that I am getting is

[image]

TheExpected Output

| customerId | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:89481 | 09/30/2012 | 784 |
| BS:89481 | 11/30/2012 | 313 |
| BS:89480 | 11/30/2012 | 1277 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a `PCollection` of `Row`s then you can use [Schema-aware PTransforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#662-schema-transforms). For your case, you may want to use "Grouping aggregations" and it can be something like this:

```
Group.byFieldNames("customerId", "date")
     .aggregateField("amount", Sum.ofIntegers(), "totalAmount")
```

It will group the rows by customer id and date, and then count a total amount for them per day. If you want to count it per month, then you need to create a new column (or modify a current one) with just a date in month format and group it by id and this column.

Also, it can be useful to use `Selected.flattenedSchema` to flatten an output schema. [Beam Schema API](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas) allows to work with Schema-aware PCollections in a very simple and effective way.

Another option could be to implement your GroupBy/Aggregate logic manually with `KV`s but it's more complicated and error-prone since it will require much more boilerplate code.

Comment: Sorry to sound silly, I have am not sure how to proceed with your suggestion. I am a newbie to apacheBeam.  I even tried looking at few examples for Group.byFieldNames. I even had  looked to this example. 

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/transforms/GroupTest.java 

But could not figure how to get it working.

Comment: I have tried adding Group.byFieldNames("customerId", "date")
     .aggregateField("amount", Sum.ofIntegers(), "totalAmount")

to my code to my code but it just prints out Group.CombineFieldsByFields as a result. I have tried this for entire day to get this working.

Comment: Could you share a code of your pipeline here?

Comment: I have updated the code!!

Comment: What was an error when you did "rows.apply(Group.byFieldNames()...)"?

Comment: It throws compilation error and it is apply(PTransform<? super PCollection<Row>,OutputT>) in the type PCollection<Row> is not applicable for the arguments (Group.CombineFieldsByFields<Object>)
]

Comment: You need to specify a type for "byFieldNames()" method. See an example here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/6173abb2e241865d89dff9ae679f4d422be84ee9/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/transforms/GroupTest.java#L328

Comment: After much effort, I am very near my result. And I have updated my answer in the question itself. Kindly have a look at it. The code is present in "Corrected Code:".

Comment: The last issue which I am facing is through the result is in form of Row, when I try to print it the result appears as key and values. I guess..  could you suggest a workaround for it.

Comment: You need to flatten your result schema with "Select.flattenedSchema()" PTransform. So, it should be something like this (no tested):  "aggregagte.apply(Select.flattenedSchema()).apply(ParDo.of(new RowToString()))"

Comment: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas has a lot of information and examples about how to use Schema API

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help provided by @Alexey Romanenko

Final solution is:

```
public class GroupByTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("We are about to start!!");

        final File schemaFile = new File(
                "C:\\AI\\Workspace\\office\\lombok\\artifact\\src\\main\\resources\\schema_transform2.avsc");

        File csvFile = new File(
                "C:\\AI\\Workspace\\office\\lombok\\artifact\\src\\main\\resources\\CustomerRequest-case2.csv");
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaFile);

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

        // Reading schema
        org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema beamSchema = AvroUtils.toBeamSchema(schema);

        final PCollectionTuple tuples = pipeline

                // Reading csv input
                .apply("1", FileIO.match().filepattern(csvFile.getAbsolutePath()))

                // Reading files that matches conditions //PRashanth needs to be looked at
                .apply("2", FileIO.readMatches())

                // Reading schema and validating with schema and converts to row and returns
                // valid and invalid list
                .apply("3", ParDo.of(new FileReader(beamSchema)).withOutputTags(FileReader.validTag(),
                        TupleTagList.of(invalidTag())));

        // Fetching only valid rows
        final PCollection<Row> rows = tuples.get(FileReader.validTag()).setCoder(RowCoder.of(beamSchema));

        // Transformation
        //Convert row to KV
        final Group.CombineFieldsByFields<Row> combine = Group.<Row>byFieldNames("customerId", "date")
            .aggregateField("balance", Sum.ofDoubles(), "balances");

        final PCollection<Row> aggregagte = rows.apply(combine);

        PCollection<String> pOutput=aggregagte.apply(Select.flattenedSchema()).apply(ParDo.of(new RowToString()));
        
                        
        
        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
        System.out.println("The end");

    }

    private static String getColumnValue(String columnName, Row row, Schema sourceSchema) {
        String type = sourceSchema.getField(columnName).schema().getType().toString().toLowerCase();
        LogicalType logicalType = sourceSchema.getField(columnName).schema().getLogicalType();
        if (logicalType != null) {
            type = logicalType.getName();
        }

        switch (type) {
        case "string":
            return row.getString(columnName);
        case "int":
            return Objects.requireNonNull(row.getInt32(columnName)).toString();
        case "bigint":
            return Objects.requireNonNull(row.getInt64(columnName)).toString();
        case "double":
            return Objects.requireNonNull(row.getDouble(columnName)).toString();
        case "timestamp-millis":
            return Instant.ofEpochMilli(Objects.requireNonNull(row.getDateTime("eventTime")).getMillis()).toString();

        default:
            return row.getString(columnName);

        }
    }



}
```